# CSS considered partially when publishing website in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages, iis-8

I'm new to web development and to IIS management. When I add some styling in my tables and I run my app using IIS express everything in my html gets the exact style that I coded on my css file. However, when I publish my app into IIS everything but one table does not get any style from my css file. I have to go to the Razor View page and add the style manually to see any changes when the app is published in IIS. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: It could be a caching problem.  One hack you can use is by appending a random number after the stylesheet url.  mystylesheet.css?{random number}  This forces the css to be downloaded again.

Comment: could you please share does it happens on all the browsers or specific browser? try to clear browser cache and history setting and browse the site again. please share the code of CSS and HTML.

Comment: Well I don't know what happened but today when I came back to work now its working properly. Maybe it was the cache on my explorer? I've been just using Mozila for my tests

Comment: try to use iis client cache setting. it will disable the cache. open iis -> select site->double click HTTP Response Headers-> In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane->In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, check the box to expire Web content, select the option to expire after a specific interval or at a specific time, and then click OK.